# 'Cannot access a disposed object' error on UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting the following error when executing **userManager.ResetPasswordAsync**:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TestDb'.
Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.get_ServiceProvider()
```

I simplified the code so that it's easier to read. I'm calling the **userManager** twice in the controller lifetime. Once for generating the token and once for resetting the password:

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    // controller's constructor
    public AuthController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous, HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPass(ForgotPassViewModel model) {
        //model checks

        var user = new UserQuery(db).GetUserByUserName(model.UserName);

        //check if user exists

        var token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var url = $"{config.Url}/auth/resetpass?user={user.Id}&token={WebUtility.UrlEncode(token)}";

        // send email with the reset url

        model.Success = "An email has been sent to your email address";
        return View(model);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous, HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPass(ResetPassViewModel model) {
        //model checks

        var user = new UserQuery(db).GetUserById(model.UserId);

        //error occurs here:
        var result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Token, model.Password);

        //check result

        model.Success = "Password successfully reset";
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Later Edit:**
Here's a function from the UserQuery (as requested in comments below). I am indeed using the 'using' wrapper:

```
    public ApplicationUser GetUserByUserName(string userName) {
        using (var db = this.dbContext) {
            var user = (from u in db.Users
                        where u.UserName == userName
                        select u).SingleOrDefault();
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the logic inside GetUserByUserName method wrapped in a using block? This exception is thrown when you are disposing the object by using the using block and trying to use the same object again after the using block.

Comment: What's in your `UserQuery` class?

Comment: Thanks for replying, guys. I do have a 'using' block in each query, so I don't think that is the issue. I have updated the question with a function from my UserQuery object

Comment: Just for testing purposes I moved the call that fails right after getting the token and it still fails with the same error. Example: await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, "Test!1"); - all values here are valid and this executes right after userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync

Comment: Of course it does matter. The `using` construct is a syntactic sugar around a `try { } finally { if(object!=null) object.Dispose() }` block. This makes sure that the object is disposed as soon as possible and even then, when an exception happens. The `DbContext` in ASP.NET Core (specifically the Identity registration of it) is registered as with scope life time (1 reference for the duration of the request). But when you dispose it before the request ends, it blows up

Comment: Plus you beat the purpose of async with your `new UserQuery(db).GetUserById(model.UserId);` call, as it's not async and thus blocking your request thread

Comment: Thank you guys, I misread the first comment initially, but it totally makes sense now that is has been explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `using` construct is a syntactic sugar around a

```
DbContext context = null;
try 
{
    context = new DbContext();
    ...stuff inside the using block ...
}
finally 
{
    if(context!=null)
        context.Dispose()
}
```

It's same as calling

```
using(DbContext context = new DbContext()) 
{
    ...stuff inside the using block ...
}
```

block. This makes sure that the object is disposed as soon as possible and even when an exception happens (finally block is always called).

The `DbContext` in ASP.NET Core (specifically the ASP.NET Core Identity registration of it) is registered as with scoped life time, this means that the same reference will be returned each for the duration of the one request.

But when you prematurely dispose it (either with `using` block or by calling `.Dispose()` method yourself) before the request ends, it blows up when another method tries to access it.

The scoped life time is the recommended one, as the DbContext can use considerable amount of memory when it is very long living, because DbContext tracks changes of all records until you dispose it.

So in traditional applications without dependency injection or simple tutorials you create it with `new` and dispose it as soon as possible. But in an Web Application a request is pretty short-lived and scoped life-time keeps handle for most of the cases. There may be some corner cases where transient (`AddTransient` method in ASP.NET Core IoC container) lifetime is better.

If you really need transient resolution you could create a factory method and inject it to your services, something like:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<MyDbContext>>( (provider) => new Func<MyDbContext>( () => new MyDbContext()));
```

and inject it in your services/controller:

```
public class MyService 
{
    public readonly Func<MyDbContext> createMyContext;

    public MyService(Func<MyDbContext> contextFactory)
    {
        this.createContext = contextFactory;
    }

    public User GetUserById(Guid userId) 
    {
        // note we're calling the delegate here which 
        // creates a new instance every time
        using(var context = createContext()) 
        {
            return context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id = userId);
        }
    }
}
```

This won't cause the issue, but is more complicated than necessary. And if you need transactions this may not play well as the transactions are per DbContext instance and Identity will always use the scoped one

Answer (score 0):

It seems the method userManager.ResetPasswordAsync() used some delay load property of the user variable. Since the user variable is out of the DB query scope, so that the property is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you expand the answer a bit? If I understand it correctly this suggested cause may not be the issue. If I execute these 2 lines of code one after another: `var token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, "Test!1");` then I still get the same error. Executing the 2 in a row bypasses the need for my second user query (so no need to call GetUserById as the user variable is already in memory - and therefore no loading delay).

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my custom User queries with the built in userManager queries that do the same thing and it works now:

In **ForgotPass** function:

```
var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.UserName);
```

In **ResetPass** function:

```
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);
```

I'll update the answer once I know exactly **why** my initial approach didn't work.

Comment: As pointed above, the `using` block disposes the `DbContext` and Identity by default registers the `DbContext` as scoped, which is preferred way, so you don't have to explicitly dispose it as it will be disposed at the end of the request and each request has gets it's own DbContext instance. Keeping the DbContext as singleton, would be a waste of resources (it grows up as you do queries as it has to track state of the objects) and if you resolve it transiently you wouldn't have a "request-wide transaction" scope

Comment: I assume you have the `using` blocks from some legacy MVC tutorials where the context is created within the using block like `using(var context = new DbContext()) { ... your query here ... }`. This doesn't work very well with dependency injection (except with a factory that resolves transiently), where the lifetime is controlled by the IoC/DI container

Comment: Great explanation, Tseng. It all makes sense now. Although I found a workaround myself I want to mark your answer as accepted, as it provides an in-depth explanation of what was actually going on. If you can put your comments together as an 'answer' I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!